# Why does my program gets stuck at the constructor?

Tags: c++

I'm creating a multi-chat server and my program gets stuck at the `User`'s constructor. I debugged my code and anything should work correctly. Here is my code (C++, Windows 10, Visual Studio 2019):

```
std::cout << "Before c'tor..." << std::endl;
User user(username, roomID, recvSocket, sendSocket);
std::cout << "After c'tor..." << std::endl;
```

(Note: The variables `username (std::string)`, `roomID (int)`, `recvSocket (my class Socket)` and `sendSocket (my class Socket)` are all defined and constructed).

(Note: My class `Socket` works properly, I checked it).

The code prints "Before c'tor..." successfully, but it gets stuck at the constructor. It doesn't even enter the constructor because the message "Inside c'tor..." isn't shown.

User constructor code:

```
User::User(std::string username, int roomID, Socket& conn, Socket& sender)
{
    std::cout << "Inside c'tor..." << std::endl;

    this->username = username;
    this->roomID = roomID;
    this->conn = conn;
    this->sender = sender;

    int id;
    bool flag = true;

    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "Inside loop..." << std::endl;

        id = std::rand() % 1000;

        mtx_id.lock();
        for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = usedIDs.begin(); it != usedIDs.end(); it++)
        {
            if (id == *it)
            {
                flag = false;
            }
        }
        mtx_id.unlock();

        if (flag) break;
    }

    this->userID = id;

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(mtx_id);
    usedIDs.push_back(id);
}
```

User class code:

```
class User
{
private:
    std::string username;
    int userID;
    int roomID;
    Socket conn;
    Socket sender;

public:
    User(std::string username, int roomID, Socket& conn, Socket& sender);
    User(const User& other);
    ~User();
    User& operator=(const User& other);

    std::string getUsername() const;
    int getUserID() const;
    int getRoomID() const;
    Socket getSocket() const;
    Socket getSender() const;

    std::string generateMsg(std::string msg) const;
    void sendMessagetoQueue(std::string msg) const;
};
```

It doesn't show any error or exception, it just gets stuck and stops working. Even the debugger doesn't show anything.

(Note: To test the program I wrote a simple code in Python.)

Comment: The debugger won't necessarily show anything on its own unless you either hit a breakpoint or an exception is raised. Can you try attaching it, pausing the program once it gets stuck, and dumping the stack?

Comment: At the end of the constructor, you push to `usedIDs` without holding the lock.  I don't know if that's the cause of your trouble but it doesn't look good.

Comment: Otherwise, this is going to need a [mcve].

Comment: What do you see when you trace the program execution with the debugger line by line?

Comment: @NateEldredge Added a lock_guard but it still doesn't work

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. the debugger just doesn't show anything. It hides the variables list.

Comment: It's still a race: in between the time where you check whether your id is in use, and the time when you push it to the vector, some other thread may also choose the same ID and  push it first.  You need to be holding the lock throughout.

Comment: @Matan the current location of the lock_guard makes it almost useless. Usually a guard must be created right after the resource it is supposed to control.

Comment: The debugger is either busy executing a statement, or stopped and waiting for the next command. If it is stopped, hit the "step into" command. If it is busy executing a statement, which one?

Comment: Where is `mtx_id` defined? I don't see its declaration/definition anywhere in the current samples

Comment: I would say something is definitely up with `Socket`. There's nowhere else for the constructor to get stuck. I notice you don't use member initializers (please use member initializers...), so `Socket conn, sender;` are each initialized by the default constructor and then assigned to. That seems fishy for what I assume is a resource holding class. But concretely you should check that `Socket::Socket()` is actually returning.

Comment: @Matan Regarding the output, when debugging make sure `std::cout` is flushed on every call, otherwise it might be confusing. Usage is `std::cout << strings/data << std::flush`

Comment: Problem Solved. Thank you @HTNW